# Accessing Tenant Information with Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have an application that needs to pull tenant information on a per method basis. I am using Cloud Foundry's UAA server for my Authentication and Authorization needs. I have tried to access tenant information by doing the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('project.retrieveItems')")
public List<ItemDto> retrieveAll(OAuth2Authentication token) {
    ... Code here to retrieve Identity Zone and use it to filter results. 
}
```

The OAuth2Authentication object doesn't have any information about the Tenant, only the scopes and authorizations. Is there anyway to get this information from a method?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IdentityZoneHolder.get()
```

will return the current tenant that is being accessed within the UAA (if you're coding within the UAA itself)

But I take it that you are asking about your application, the core Spring Security Oauth2 implementation has no idea about `tenants`

It only has awareness of a token url and a check token url.

Comment: Yeah, I am wondering how to access from within my application. Would I have to define some sort of custom token handler to add the tenant?

Comment: Correct. You'd want to intercept the call to /check_token. This would return all the claims that you need to be aware of. Including zone id, which is the tenant information